# S/MIME and Office 365

Tags: email, certificate, office365, smime

I am new to the topic and started to search on the web to understand how should I proceed.
I basically need to add a certificate to sign the emails sent from the company I work with, using Office 365.
From what I have understood, or the certificate can be self signed and created by myself but then all the customers need to install it manually first in order to read our emails, or, I can pay for one from Comodo, Symantec, etc. deploy it to Office 365 and start to send signed emails. Of course I need to choose the type of certificate (DV, EV, EC...) and the encryption level. That's it or I missed a step ? Please correct me if am wrong and any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: Your employer should be providing the certificate.  Signing your emails with a certificate only you have won’t really do anything.  Your employer won’t be able to verify your digital identity.

Comment: Let say my employer has no idea how to provide a certificate, how can I verify my digital identity ?

Comment: You would have to provide them the public key and sign emails with your private key.  However, unless your employer trusts the certificate, that doesn't really buy you anything